# Resource cleanup after each test

Tags: robotframework

I'm using robot framework to test a REST API and as such I do have to create many temporary resources (test user or any other resource). Those are abstracted in keyword, but I need to clean them up after each test. But I would like to not worry about cleaning that explicitly in each test since it would require our test case to "play" at different levels of abstraction.

What would be great would be to have the keyword teardown running after the testcase is completed instead of directly after the keyword is completed.

I did some research but haven't found a good way to handle that.

Is there any solution to clean up resources created in a keyword at the end of a test case without doing it explicitly in the test case?

here is a code example to illustrate the situation:

helper.robot

```
*** Keywords ***
    a user exists
       create a user

    Delete user
       actually remove the user
```

test.robot
Resource         helper.robot

```
*** Test Cases ***
test user can login
    Given a user exists
    When user login
    Then it succeeds

    [Teardown]    Delete user
```

What I want is to move the teardown out of the test case to some other way that deletes the user after each test case, but without specifying if in each test case. I don’t want to configure that exact teardown at the setting level since we don’t always use the same resource for all test cases.

Comment: So what is actually your question? You did mention teardown so you are obviously familiar with the concept; you're wondering - how it used in RobotFramework? Or where to set it, on individual tests or blanket in the suite declaration? Or how it should encompass all your resources? :) It's hard to deduct, what you've put so far is a statement, not really a question :)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to the issue explained then proposed solution i tried. What i want is a way to clean up resource that are created inside keyword an thus abstracted in the test case without having to manage this clean up from the test case level. The teardown solution doesn't work since it either run to early (if in keyword) or at the wrong abstraction level (in test case)

Comment: teardown gets executed after each test , or after each suite . Not after each keyword . What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @PDHide is it clearer with the example?

Comment: Let me take another stab at my understanding of your issue - reading the comments, what I think you try to accomplish is - an universal teardown/cleanup defined once, that will delete only the objects created in the concrete case (and not others, that are not created here, but might be in some other case)?

Comment: That's one way to put it

Answer (score 0):

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown

> At the time of writing, the only special tags are robot:exit, that is
> automatically added to tests when stopping test execution gracefully,
> and robot:no-dry-run, that can be used to disable the dry run mode.
> More usages are likely to be added in the future.
> 2.2.6   Test setup and teardown
>
> Robot Framework has similar test setup and teardown functionality as
> many other test automation frameworks. In short, a test setup is
> something that is executed before a test case, and a test teardown is
> executed after a test case. In Robot Framework setups and teardowns
> are just normal keywords with possible arguments.
>
> Setup and teardown are always a single keyword. If they need to take
> care of multiple separate tasks, it is possible to create higher-level
> user keywords for that purpose. An alternative solution is executing
> multiple keywords using the BuiltIn keyword Run Keywords.
>
> The test teardown is special in two ways. First of all, it is executed
> also when a test case fails, so it can be used for clean-up activities
> that must be done regardless of the test case status. In addition, all
> the keywords in the teardown are also executed even if one of them
> fails. This continue on failure functionality can be used also with
> normal keywords, but inside teardowns it is on by default.
>
> The easiest way to specify a setup or a teardown for test cases in a
> test case file is using the Test Setup and Test Teardown settings in
> the Setting table. Individual test cases can also have their own setup
> or teardown. They are defined with the [Setup] or [Teardown] settings
> in the test case table and they override possible Test Setup and Test
> Teardown settings. Having no keyword after a [Setup] or [Teardown]
> setting means having no setup or teardown. It is also possible to use
> value NONE to indicate that a test has no setup/teardown.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup       Open Application    App A
Test Teardown    Close Application

*** Test Cases ***
Default values
    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown from setting table
    Do Something

Overridden setup
    [Documentation]    Own setup, teardown from setting table
    [Setup]    Open Application    App B
    Do Something

No teardown
    [Documentation]    Default setup, no teardown at all
    Do Something
    [Teardown]

No teardown 2
    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown can be disabled also with special value NONE
    Do Something
    [Teardown]    NONE

Using variables
    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown specified using variables
    [Setup]    ${SETUP}
    Do Something
    [Teardown]    ${TEARDOWN}
```

if you provide it in settings , it works as you want you don't have to specify for each test case

Comment: That only explain the usage of tear down, it doesn't solve the main issue that is cleaning up resources that were actually created at deeper abstraction level.

Comment: @JonatanCloutier creata  keyword that does taht and call that in teardown

Comment: This is exactly the example I gave that we want to change since we do need to know at high levels the cleanup requires at low levels.

Comment: @Jonatan robotframewrk Is just an abstraction of python , so if you don't want bring the teardown then do that in listener class

Comment: There might be something to do with listener class, but it's not as straightforward as what I would hope. Thanks for the suggestion